# php script to move data between columns with mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

What I want to achieve is to move the data between 2 rows within one table.

```
Column A
--------
FN2
1 200x310mm
2 400x260mm[+0.84]
3 500x500mm[+11.34]

Column B
--------
0.0000   
0.0000    
0.0000    
0.0000
```

This is how it should look like after the data move:

```
Column A
--------
FN2
1 200x310mm
2 400x260mm
3 500x500mm

Column B
--------
0.0000   
0.0000    
+0.84    
+11.34
```

What I want is that the query between the [ ] is moved to column B and replaces the 0.0000

How can I achieve this?

Kind Regards

Comment: do you want to move all data of columnA to ColumnB respectively?

Comment: Only the content between the two [ ], see the last to items in the example above.

Comment: then you first fetch all records then check every field of column with [] then replace it

Comment: Are you sure you want '1','2',and '3' in the same column as the dimensions? That seems really messy!

Answer (score 1):

just to illustrate what Yadav said

```
$query = "SELECT columnID, columnA FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$id = $row['columnID'];
$a = $row['columnA'];

$pos1 = strpos($a,"[")+1;
$pos2 = strpos($a,"]");

$b = substr($a,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1);

$query = "UPDATE table SET columnB = $b WHERE columnID = $id";
mysql_query($query,$conn);


}//end while
```

edit: Yadav obviously proposed a better answer while I was typing mine...

Comment: @YadavChetan: thx, I liked your regex approach but I code a lot for people with limited php skills so I have to keep my code clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for you here i used id as unique key ... and test is my database

```
<?php 
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db("test");
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test where columnA LIKE '%[%]'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        if(preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/',$row['columnA'],$match))
        {            
           mysql_query("UPDATE test SET columnB='".$match[1][0]."' WHERE id=".$row['id']."");
        }
    }

?>
```